# Term by term differentiation of sin z

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

In complex numbers, $\sin\:z$ is expanded as the series
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{align*}
 with pointwise convergence (right?)

Then, when we find an expansion of cosine by using term by term differentiation? I think that I should show that this series uniformly converges to $\sin\:z$.
Then, How can I show that without using Taylor theorem ?

Comment: Wrong; this is not the Taylor series of $\sin z$;)

Comment: looks cosiney to me. Also better (imo) to write $z^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin z = \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}.$$

> Theorem.
>   Let $f_n$ be sequence analytic on domain $D$. If $f_n$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $D$ , then $f_n$ analytic on $D$.
>
> Property.
>   If powerseries centered at $z_0$ has radius R of converge, then the powerseries converes uniformly on everycompact subset lying in domain where power series converges.

So,  $\sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1}z^{2n+1}.$ is analytic on complex plane.

> Theorem.
>   $f_n$ is sequence in domain D. If $\sum f_n$ converges in D and converges uniformly on every compact subset of D, then $\sum f_n$ is analytic on D and its derivative is $\sum f_n ^\prime$

You can get result that you have wanted.